# Is there any bioacoustics research team(s) in New York City (USA)?

Tags: fieldwork

I'm a science journalist in New York City (USA) interested in reporting on bioacoustics research. Does anyone know of (or do!) any bioacoustic research in or near New York City (~3-hr drive)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I feel this is more of a discussion question and would not be of use of anyone else than the user itself. This person should try to reach out on other platform dedicated to discussion and reach out.

Comment: @AmandineGasc I started a meta post to discuss this question here: https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-should-we-handle-outreach-type-questions-are-they-on-or-off-topic

Comment: I would also recommend posting this on Wildlabs (https://wildlabs.net/), which is a better platform for these sorts of questions/discussions!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about making specific connections for an individual, is subjective, and may change over time so it is not a good fit for the BSE Q/A format.

Comment: Voting to close because I think this is better suited for another platofrm, not BSE. Thanks for starting the meta discussion @selene

Answer (score 6):

While likely slightly outside your ideal travel radius, the Cornell University K. Lisa Yang Center for Conservation Bioacoustics in Ithaca, New York would be a wonderful group to reach out to as they conduct a broad range of terrestrial, aquatic, and marine bioacoustic research.

There is also Joseph D. Warren at the School of Marine and Atmospheric Sciences at Stony Brook University who conducts research on marine bioacoustics.

I'm fairly sure there must be others, but those were the two options I thought of first. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[I](https://carlybatist.commons.gc.cuny.edu/) am a bioacoustician based at the CUNY Graduate Center (GC)! I focus on lemur vocalizations.

[David Lahti](https://www.gc.cuny.edu/people/david-c-lahti) (also at CUNY, at Queens College & the GC) works on bioacoustics as well, with a focus on birds.